# Configuring sticky sessions for a scala + lift app

Tags: scala, glassfish, nginx, lift

I'm working on a scala + lift web application and am considering how to set everything up. I'll be running this in Amazon EC2 and I can have a fairly flexible architecture.

My current approach is to use ELB configured with sticky sessions (lift requirement), an nginx frontend, with glassfish (or perhaps jetty) in the backend. nginx would be nice for url rewriting and pushing static content (although putting my static content into an Amazon S3 bucket is under consideration). I'm unsure if I should throw out ELB and use HAProxy instead. I'll need to be adding and removing glassfish instances to dynamically scale according to load. Can nginx dynamically load balance across multiple glassfish instances? Do I need to maintain a 1:1 ratio of nginx to glassfish instances? Will ELB + nginx handle this appropriately? How would you configure ELB/nginx/glassfish so this would work? Does it make sense to use nginx? Should I just load balance directly across a glassfish cluster?

Thanks for any help you can provide!